# MVC Route not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Update:**

As someone pointed out I was missing an s in my Route registration.  Now I have a secondary problem.

This is how I want it to work:

http://localhost/products/  -->  ProductsController.Index()

http://localhost/products/3/apples  --> ProductsController.Details(int? id, string productName)

This is what currently happens:

http://localhost/products goes to my Details action.

How do I set up the routes for this?

I set up the following routes in my Global.asx file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ViewProduct",
        "products/{id}/{productName}",
        new { controller = "Products", action = "Details", id = 0, productName = "" } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

I have the following controller:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Products/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Product> products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Id = 57349, ProductName = "Apple" },
            new Product { Id = 57350, ProductName = "Banana" }
        };

        return View(products);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int? id, string productName)
    {
        Product p = new Product { Id = id.Value, ProductName = productName };

        return View(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of iis do you use?

Comment: I'm not using IIS. I'm using the built in Visual Studio Web Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have defined default values for `id` and `productName` the routing engine just fills those in for you when they are missing, so your request to /products is getting those defaults inserted and going to the details action.

Take out: `id = 0, productName = ""` and you'll get the expected behavior.

**edit**

Consider having an {action} parameter in there. Since you have a default action and no way to override it you may have everything routed to details anyway.

Comment: Should I also change the controller action so it is int instead of int? (nullable)? That didn't really make sense to me.

Comment: If the int always needs to be there (which appears to be the case) then I'd just make it a non-nullable int. Could help you catch bugs later.

Comment: Yeah it should always be there. Was just following someone else's example. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a "s" in your route declaration

action = "Detail**s**"

Or have one exceeding "s" in your action name :

public ActionResult Detail**s**(int? id, string productName)

It's up to you to decide which one to correct ;)

Update : for the route update just use :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ViewProduct",
    "products/{id}/{productName}",
    new { 
        controller = "Products", 
        action = "Details" }
);
```

So when you type /products the "Default" route gets used.

Comment: Oh nice catch. Now when I hit /products it's taking me to the Details action when I want it to hit the Index action. Do I need to set up another route?

Comment: No... you just say what is default action (Details), but you can hit the action you want just by passing its name in an address like `http://localhost/products/Index/`

Comment: Yeah but I want /products/ to default to /products/index basically.